# Issue with a dialog and draggable Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, jquery-dialog

I'm using a dialog box from jQuery UI and FullCalendar

My dialog opens correctly, but when its over my calendar it is like the dialog gets integrated in the calender as a draggable object. I have a drag/droppable calendar. And if I get the dialogWindow inside the calendar it takes it as an object.

My dialog:

```
$('#exercisechoise').dialog({

  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  title: 'Chouse Session',
  width: 500,
  modal: true,
  buttons:{
  Save: function(){

  },
  Cancel: function(){

  }
  } 
});
$("#exercisechoise").dialog("option","title", 'Chose session');
$("#exercisechoise").dialog('open');
```

FullCalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  theme: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  header: {
     left: 'today prev,next',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  minTime: '06:00',
  maxTime: '22:00',
  allDaySlot: false,
  axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
  columnFormat: {
     month: 'ddd',
     week: 'ddd dd/MM',
     day: 'dddd M/d'
  },
  timeFormat: {  // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
     month: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}',
     week: 'H(:mm){ - H:mm}',
     agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'
  },
  eventSources: ['exercise/xhrGetListings/'+userid],

  droppable: true,
......
```

html header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>/temp/jquery-ui-1.9.2.le/css/le-frog/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>menumaster/fg.menu.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/public/js/timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

[image: dialogbox and fullcalendar]

any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting `draggable: false` on your dialog? I believe it is set to `true` by default.

Comment: @ganeshk Yes have also tried that and it is the same as the pic. When the dialog is inside the calendar it turns inside it

Comment: do you need dragging in your calendar? if not try setting diableDraggin to true http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/disableDragging/

Comment: @keshav Yes I need the draggeble function of the calendar im affraid

Comment: @kenshav I did try to disable the dragging in fullcalendar now to maybe work out a new solution bit its the same.

Comment: it looks like a css problem as I use ui-widget-content in both the calendar and dialog.

is it some sort of way to say that the dialog alwys shall be in front of all other contents.

Comment: @Simmern you can try setting the z-index of the dialog

Comment: @keshav it worked perfektly fine, thanks for the help.